# Cannot access SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I don't know why I cannot access my SharePoint site. All the users from AD cannot access except Farm Account. it always prompt to type username and password. Any advice please.

Comment: It seems like an issue with User Profile Synchronisation service.

Comment: Don't know but all services seem working properly, and currently I am using SharePoint foundation 2013, but my team he has do the window update yesterday, after that issue happen..

Comment: Try running the configuration wizard. This is required after installing any updates.

Comment: does effect to any data?

Comment: Still same after re-config any more advice please ..

Comment: what updates applied? how many servers? did you run the config wizard on all servers?

Comment: All services are working fine.. Yes, I run all

Comment: are you accessing site from server or pc? what type of authentication you are using?

Comment: Both, and I am using NTLM authentication. current only SP farm account can access, other still can not.

Comment: From log: Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0

Comment: It seem SharePoint cannot retrieve the username and password from AD (server 2003)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Issue, it because of our windows update on AD.!

I has remove the KB3002657 (Vulnerability in NETLOGON Could Allow Spoofing (3002657)) then I restart the AD and then SharePoint is comeback and working fine, Note: this will effect to on-premise Exchange Also. thanks everyone for idea, and advice.
[image]